# Complex Number Application in Isosceles Triangle Incentre

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> On the Argand plane $z_1, z_2$ and $z_3$ are respectively the vertices
> of an isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ with $AC = BC$ and equal angles are $θ$. If
> $z_4$ is the incentre of the triangle then prove that $(z_2 – z_1 )
>  (z_3 – z_1 ) = (1 + \sec θ) (z_4 – z_1 )^2$

I applied Coni's method of rotation of unit vectors (involving complex numbers).

$$(z_2-z_1)/|z_2-z_1|e^{i\theta/2}=(z_4-z_2)/|z_4-z_2|$$
and $$(z_1-z_2)/|z_1-z_2|e^{i\theta/2}=(z_1-z_4)/|z_1-z_4|$$

After that what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\arg\left(\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_4-z_1}\right)=-\arg\left(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_4-z_1}\right)\tag1$$

Also, applying the law of sines to $\triangle{ACI}$ where $I(z_4)$ gives
$$\frac{|z_4-z_1|}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}=\frac{|z_3-z_1|}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\tag2$$

From $(1)(2)$,
$$\begin{align}\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_4-z_1}\cdot\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_4-z_1}&=\left|\frac{z_2-z_1}{z_4-z_1}\right|\left|\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_4-z_1}\right|\tag3\\\\&=2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\cdot\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}\\\\&=\frac{2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\theta}\\\\&=\frac{\cos\theta+1}{\cos\theta}\\\\&=1+\sec\theta\end{align}$$

---

**Added** :

Using your idea, we get
$$\frac{z_2-z_1}{|z_2-z_1|}e^{\pm\frac{i\theta}{2}}=\frac{z_4-z_1}{|z_4-z_1|}=\frac{z_3-z_1}{|z_3-z_1|}e^{\mp\frac{i\theta}{2}}$$
from which we have $(3)$. The result follows from this.

Comment: Good.But can something be done from my method too?

Comment: @ZOZ: I've noticed that you ask "After that what to do". I've tried to find something helpful to your method, but I couldn't. So, I decided to post my method.

Comment: No problem.But I was trying to find a method using rotation of complex number as my maths teacher told it is possible but I still could'nt figure it out.Anyway thank you :-)

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I don't accept your answer right now!I want to keep the question visible as unanswered for some more time..

Comment: @ZOZ: Of course, I don't mind :) I'll keep searching another method.

Comment: @ZOZ: See the addition in my answer.